# Count unique names (based on gender) using pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table which consist of 7 students and three age ranges (<=13, 14-17 and 18-20). I want to count the number of students that fall into these age ranges (based on their gender)  using pivot table. I was able to use pivot table to categorize the students under the different age ranges but I'm not able to get the total number of students for each range. How do I go about it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: put the student name in the values also.

Comment: @Craner If I do that I'll have 8 for each age range which makes a total of 24 instead of 7 (3+2+2 for each range).

Comment: Ah, i misunderstood what you wanted.

Comment: @RetiredGeek I did that but couldn't find any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you need in the `Values` section is a "distinct count" of the student names.

**I'm not sure what you mean when you write "by gender" as you do not show your desired results*

In order for this to show up when you Insert a Pivot Table, select the Option to `Add to Data Model`

[image]

Then, when you select the `Value Field Settings`, you'll see the distinct count option

[image]

**Voila!**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. For me not to have initially seen the distinct count option, I thought I was lazy when it cones to scrolling down until I realize it is related to the add-to-data-model option. Please explain this. As for the gender stuff, all I needed to do was to put the gender field in the column area which worked great.

Comment: @Jovanny Glad to help.  And I don't know why the `add to data model` brings up that option. Ran across it some years ago.